# Mongodb schema design validation

Tags: mongodb, database-schema, nosql

I am building an app which allows users to do some "tasks" to earn points. The "tasks" are part of a "campaign" which themselves are a part of "brands". I am confused about the schema for storing the response of the users. This is what i have built. All tasks have some activities which a user needs to complete to complete the task.

```
{ _id : ObjectId,
  user_id : ObjectId,
  campaign : [ 
        { _id : ObjectId,
          campaign_id : ObjectId,
          brand_id : ObjectId,
          completed : Boolean,
          points : Number,
          tasks : [
             { _id : ObjectId,
               task_id : ObjectId,
               start_time : Date,
               rewards : points,
               responses : [
                     { _id : ObjectId,
                       activity_id : ObjectId,
                       response : Mixed, 
                    }...]
             }...]
       }...]
}
```

Queries:
1. inserting new response and updating how many no. of people doing the campaign of the given task.
2. getting completed tasks and respective rewards of a user.
3. getting completed campaigns of a user.
4. updating a user's response to a task.
5. finding unique responses by all users for a given activity.

Problems :
1.The problem is that this schema contains nested arrays and mongodb doesnt allow me to use positional operators after level 1.

It would be helpful if someone can suggest a design which can perform these queries in a better way.

EDIT :

I have broken the above collection into two collections to facilitate the query system and at the same time maintain the sense with which the entitites should exist in the system.

collection 1 : user_tasks (stores user's attempted campaigns and tasks)

```
{ _id :ObjectId,
  user_id : ObjectId,
  campaigns : [ 
       { _id : ObjectId,
          campaign_id :ObjectId,
          completed : Boolean,
          points : Number,   
          tasks : [ObjectId]
       }...]
}
```

collection 2 : user_responses

```
{ _id : ObjectId,
  user_id : ObjectId,
  task_id : ObjectId,
  rewards : Number,
  responses :[
        { _id : ObjectId,
          activity_id : ObjectId,
          response : Mixed
        } ... ]
}
```

This allows me to have a simpler query system specially in updating and inserting responses and calculating leader board for a specific a specific task.

Comment: I'd like to know a bit more about the use case. What is a response to a task? What exactly does it mean to complete a task or a campaign? How do responses relate to completion?

Comment: A task is a question or a series of questions which are activities in the system. Completing all activities completes a task and completing all the tasks in the campaign complete a campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create collections dedicated to tasks and responses. It *will* require you to write some 'relational plumbing' logic on the server-side. That's the price to pay for using MongoDB. Some libraries provide helpers to assist you in this (such as Mongoose's `populate` operator).

Having a collections graph with a big diameter does have some drawbacks, because it may make your queries more complex and require more roundtrips between your MongoDB client and your database. Therefore, there is indeed an incentive to use subdocuments instead of foreign collections.

How to strike a middle ground between having one monolithic collection and too many light collections? Here are some questions to ask yourself:

1. Do I risk exceeding the document's size limit?
2. In my information model, should the parent entity know about the child entities, or can it exist and make sense without them?
3. Am I building a whole *ad hoc* querying / indexing engine on the client side just to reach the sub-documents?

Comment: I understand that none of the schemas are completely correct or wrong and there are trade-offs in each of them but my thinking behind creating this schema was that a task doesn have an identity except when the user is saving response to it and it also becomes easier to fetch user's tasks grouped by campaign. The only problem is that of updating specific responses

Comment: If you *really* want to stick to this schema, you'll have to load the campaign on you server, scan it for the right task, find the response in that task, update the response, and save your campaign again. But again, I highly doubt your statement on tasks not being important enough to have their own collection, and it will only get worse as you refine your application :).

Comment: Yes. I guess i am seeing it now. Do you think it makes sense to make a new collection for responses and keep the rest of the schema as such ?
That way, I will not have to break the hierarchy of the campaigns and tasks and can still indicidually update and analyze respones

Comment: I am not too optimistic about that approach - but nothing stops you from doing it as a first migration step. I'll edit my answer to help you reason about this.

Comment: I agree with Valentin. IMHO, if you have _ids in subdocuments or if your query gets even remotely as complicated as a typical SQL query, you're doing it *badly* wrong. If it has an id, it needs a collection, period. Also remember that objects have owners, and concurrent writes must be made atomic. That will move more and more logic in the queries and then you're in the SQL mess.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, according to the 3 points you mentioned,  the last schema design was breaking the 3rd one. Also, It was really difficult (complex) to get to a specific response. The only reason I haven't created a new collection for storing user's task is that it makes no sense for them to exists without the campaign. What do you think about the new one ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to topple your design upside down. Basically make it Task centric.

Have 4 main collections in your DB.

1. User
2. Tasks
3. Brand
4. Campaigns

By doing this, you would have no issues scaling out, and at the same time, your data managements would become a breeze.

Comment: making it task centric makes it really difficult to get everything w.r.t the user and that is how the app functions.

Comment: you can have the info about the Brand and Campaign in the Tasks as brand_id and compaign_id, and assinee_id (this is user) -  then getting the tasks for each of the different scenarios would be really easy.